# Debugging LUA in a game using ZeroBrane Studio's remote debugging feature

Tags: zerobrane

I have gone through [the remote debugging section of documentation](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging) that explains how to set this up. There is a difficulty curve because of the unfamiliar terminology used on the document. I want to use ZBS to remotely debug LUA-based add-ons running in a game called The Elder Scrolls Online for now (and others like World of Warcraft later). Has anyone successfully set this up? It doesn't have to be ESO. I can figure it out if you set up for another game. Care to share how you set it up using laymen terms briefly? *A video would be amazing!*

Thank you and divines bless you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `mobdebug.lua` and `luasocket` libraries available to your application. The documentation you referenced describes how those libraries can be referenced (as they come bundled with the IDE itself), but you can use any other way to get them included with your application. As long as the libraries are available, you can then run `require('mobdebug').start()` in your application to connect to the instance of the IDE running on the same computer. If it's running on another computer, provide the IP/name of the computer as the first parameter to the `start()` function.